# Django - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bootstrap5'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to run a django app which is made by some other developer. First I got *ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_heroku'*That was solved by *pip install django-heroku*. Now I am getting this error.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bootstrap5'
```

Then I did this

```
pip install django-bootstrap5
```

It looks like it installed bootstrap5. But when I try to run again the app I am getting same error.Here is the what it shows.

```
(venv) D:\django\multi-vendor-shop-management-main>python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 910, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "D:\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "D:\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "D:\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 398, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "D:\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "D:\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "D:\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 228, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bootstrap5'
```

When I do *pip install django-bootstrap5* again, It gives me this

```
(venv) D:\django>pip install django-bootstrap5
Requirement already satisfied: django-bootstrap5 in d:\django\venv\lib\site-packages (21.3)
Requirement already satisfied: Django>=2.2 in d:\django\venv\lib\site-packages (from django-bootstrap5) (4.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4>=4.8.0 in d:\django\venv\lib\site-packages (from django-bootstrap5) (4.11.1)
Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>1.2 in d:\django\venv\lib\site-packages (from beautifulsoup4>=4.8.0->django-bootstrap5) (2.3.2.post1)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse>=0.2.2 in d:\django\venv\lib\site-packages (from Django>=2.2->django-bootstrap5) (0.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: tzdata in d:\django\venv\lib\site-packages (from Django>=2.2->django-bootstrap5) (2022.1)
Requirement already satisfied: asgiref<4,>=3.4.1 in d:\django\venv\lib\site-packages (from Django>=2.2->django-bootstrap5) (3.5.1)
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.3; however, version 22.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'D:\django\venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

What can I do now? I am new to django.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The preferred way to install django-bootstrap-v5 is:

$ pip install django-bootstrap-v5

According to [documentation](https://django-bootstrap-v5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)

Comment: run it. It shows- Requirement already satisfied

Comment: Run: Python manage.py runserver **again** and see what's happened

Comment: Ok had another error but now it is running I guess. Thanks

Comment: What are the second error please ?

Comment: I did not migrate.So I think the data tables were not updated. After migration now I think it is running

Comment: Are you thinking that it will run or it already running ? Please specify your solution.

Comment: Yes It is running

Answer (score 1):

django-bootstrap5

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    # ...
    "django_bootstrap5",
    # ...
)
```

django-bootstrap-v5 is a different module

Answer (score 0):

```
{% load django_bootstrap5 %}
```

to your template